# Using DFS algorithm to flood-fill a shape

Tags: c++, sdl, depth-first-search

I am working on a project that must be something like windows's paint. I've already implemented 8 tools (which are brush, rectangle, oval, polygon, triangle, line, spray and filler tool). Now I want to make a "bucket" tool which must fill the area around itself. 
I use DFS algorithm for this tool but when the area is large, gdb give below errors:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7c47f9d in _IO_new_file_xsputn (f=0xb7d82ac0 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, data=0xbf80009e, n=6)
    at fileops.c:1273
1273    fileops.c: No such file or directory.
```

Does anyone know what does this error mean?
You can see bucket.h and bucket.cpp below:

bucket.h:

```
#ifndef BUCKET_H
#define BUCKET_H

#include "tool.h"

#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_gfxPrimitives.h"

#include <cmath>

class Bucket : public Tool {
    private:
        bool **mark;
        Color selectedPointColor;
    public:
        Bucket( bool state, SDLKey key ) : Tool( state, key ) {}

        virtual void draw( SDL_Surface*, int, int, int, int, int, Color color );

        friend void DFS( SDL_Surface*, int, int, Color, bool** );
        friend Color getColor( SDL_Surface*, int, int );
};

inline Color getColor( SDL_Surface *screen, int x, int y ){
    Uint32* pixel = (Uint32*) screen->pixels;
    Uint8* color = (Uint8*) &( pixel[ y * screen->w + x ] );
    return Color( (int) color[2], (int) color[1], (int) color[0] );
}

inline void DFS( SDL_Surface *screen, int x, int y, Color color, Color selectedPointColor ){
    static int counter;
    counter++;
    cout << counter << endl;
    pixelRGBA( screen, x, y, color.red(), color.green(), color.blue(), 255 );

    if ( x + 1 < screen->w && getColor( screen, x + 1, y ) == selectedPointColor )
        DFS( screen, x + 1, y, color, selectedPointColor );

    if ( y + 1 < screen->h && getColor( screen, x, y + 1 ) == selectedPointColor )
        DFS( screen, x, y + 1, color, selectedPointColor );

    if ( x - 1 >= 0 && getColor( screen, x - 1, y) == selectedPointColor )
        DFS( screen, x - 1, y, color, selectedPointColor );

    if ( y - 1 >= 0 && getColor( screen, x, y - 1) == selectedPointColor )
        DFS( screen, x, y - 1, color, selectedPointColor );
}

#endif
```

bucket.cpp:

```
#include "bucket.h"

void Bucket::draw( SDL_Surface *screen, int x, int y, int, int, int, Color color ){
    selectedPointColor = getColor( screen, x, y );
    if ( selectedPointColor == color )
        return;
    DFS( screen, x, y, color, this->selectedPointColor );
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that a full stack gdb gives you (only 1 frame)? Hard to say but maybe it's as simple as stack overflow (as it happens only for big areas and DFS() is called recursively)?

Comment: "Welcome to Stack Overflow" seems appropriate for multiple reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's stack overflow. If you fill a large space which has a simple shape (like a rectangle), the depth of recursion will be roughly equal to the area of that space, because it will almost always go to some branch and not return.

That is if image is e.g 1000x1000, the depth of recursion is about one million, which is too much.

You shouldn't use DFS for flood-filling, use BFS instead.